# ffmpeg - merge multiple audio at DIFFERENT times?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to write a script that will take an arbitrary number of of .wav files and create a single output .wav file from them. The tricky part is that each component .wav file must start *n* seconds into the final output file. For example, if i have the files beep1.wav, beep2.wav, and beep3.wav, the resulting output.wav should be a mono sound file where the contents of beep2.wav will be heard starting at the 1-second mark, the contents of beep3.wav at the 2-second mark, etc.  The script doesn't know beforehand how long each of the source audio files will be, so a simple `-filter_complex` using `concat` didn't work.  Using the `amix` filter didn't work either ; although i was able to combine an arbitrary number of input files, they all started at the same time, because i haven't been able to delay the onset of each individual component audio file beforehand. I also tried `-itsoffset` and that appears to do nothing at all, regardless of where i position it.

Does anyone have an idea how I might approach this ?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1092346

Comment: @Gyan excellent !  thank you, that works a charm. :)